# How to create a corresponding ViewController class for a Storyboard ViewController in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard, visual-studio-mac

In a Xamarin iOS project, I have been using `add -> new file -> ViewController` and that creates a UIViewController class, a Designer file, and an XIB file. Everything is all well there.

I am now however making use of  Main.storyboard and I added a new ViewController there (`ProjectsViewController`). I have already given it that class name inside Identity inspection, even though such a class doesn't exist yet.

I would like to get a view controller class for `ProjectsViewController` and I know I cannot just create `ProjectsViewController.cs` that inherits from UIVIewController.

What are the linking steps? I should eventually be able to access my controller outlets inside Xamarin (c# interface).

Answer (score 0):

You can directly create `ViewController` outlet inside storyboard ,it will automatically create class in your project .

1. Open `Main.storyboard` with Xcode .
2. Create a ViewController inside storyboard.

[image]

3. Name the ViewController .

[image]

4. Save and open visual studio ,you will see that

[image]

Comment: @pnizzle Is there anything to update ?